# Using trigger to active a trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to write a trigger to activate another trigger? Or can i put the 2 trigger into 1 trigger?

Comment: yes it is, but you should try not to...

Comment: What exactly is your requirement?

Comment: It would be better to tell us what you want to achieve rather than asking us whether something is possible.  You have given so little detail, the answer to your question is YES or NO or MAYBE, depending on what you really mean.  Please *edit* your question to make it more helpful.

Comment: Also, please give us the database version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers fire when the appropriate DML issues against their table.  There is no concept of calling a trigger.

If you want to share code across difference events, that is easy to do:

```
create or replace trigger ins_upd_emp 
before insert or update on emp
for each row
begin
     --  do this only for new records
     if inserting then
          :new.id := emp_seq.nextval;
     end if;

     --  do this for all records
     :new.last_activity_user := user;
     :new.last_activity_date := sysdate;
end;
```

Note how the INSERTING keyword isolates activity for one event.   Use these keywords when you want to share some actions but not all of them.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#CIHEHBEB).

Please bear in mind that triggers allow us to get into terrible muddles, precisely because their calls are out of our control.  Only use triggers for the simplest of operations.  Building complex logic into triggers is bad for a number of reasons:

1. performance can be poor for multi-row statements
2. triggers are invisible; developers always forget to check them when diagnosing a problem
3. making triggers do things they're not supposed leads to horrible kludges.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add BELOW TO ENABLE

*ALTER TRIGGER trigger_name ENABLE*

or FOR Disable

*ALTER TRIGGER trigger_name DISABLE*